# A class with generics referencing itself as the type of that generic in Java

Tags: java

I have several classes that are subclasses of Animal which itself is a subclass of Lifeform. All of these classes has a child that will always be of it's own type hence the generic. Simplified code below:

```
public class Animal<T extends Animal> extends Lifeform {
    T child;

    private void initiate() {
        setChild(Animal.class);
    }

    public void setChild(Class<T> animalType) {
        T foundChild = findChild(animalType);
        foundChild.setParent(this);
        this.child = foundChild;
    }
}
```

Where findChild is an inherited method:

```
public abstract class Lifeform {
    private <L extends Lifeform> L findChild(Class<L> lifeformType) {
        /* Do some stuff with lifeformType to find child */
        ...
        return child;
    }
}
```

Note that most Lifeforms will not have a child even though the method for identifying a child is in the Lifeform class.

I get a compilation error where I try to call setChild(Animal.class) in Animal.initiate().

> incompatible types: java.lang.Class<Animal> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T>

T extends Animal, so why can't I use Animal.class as a parameter here?

Initially I created setChild without any arguments and tried to do

```
findChild(T.class)
```

however I realized I can't get the class from a generic like that, and found that a common solution was to just add the class as a parameter which is how I ended up with what I have now.

I have no issues if I try to use setChild in a subclass:

```
public class Bat extends Animal<Bat> {
    private void fly() {
        setChild(Bat.class);
        child.fly();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there are a few cases where I actually need an instance of an animal without a subtype, hence I want to be able to setChild with Animal as type.

I realize I can probably create an extra subclass for Animal and instead have an abstract class AnimalAbstract containing the setChild method. However this would mean I would have to separate methods from Animal depending on how they are used.

Is there another way to make this work?

Comment: How does your `Lifeform` interface looks like?

Comment: @AdamArold It's an abstract class. I've added it above in simplified form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that one way to deal with this problem is to keep a reference to the class of the child:

```
public class Animal<T extends Animal> extends Lifeform {
    protected final Class<T> childClass;
    T child;

    public Animal(Class<T> childClass) {
        this.childClass = childClass;
    }

    protected void initiate() {
        setChild(childClass);
    }

    public void setChild(Class<T> animalType) {
        T foundChild = findChild(animalType);
        foundChild.setParent(this);
        this.child = foundChild;
    }
}
```

The Bat class would then become:

```
public class Bat extends Animal<Bat> {
    public Bat() {
        super(Bat.class);
    }

    private void fly() {
        setChild(Bat.class); // or initiate();
        child.fly();
    }
}
```